# Creating a numeric index using py2neo?

Tags: python, neo4j, numeric, py2neo

Using neo4j via py2neo. I need to be able to query using CYPHER for numeric values, using an index. For example,
START n=node:field_index("subdomain:Football AND type:Competition AND weight>10") RETURN n;

Weight should be indexed as a numeric field in lucene. This query results in

org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.RepresentationExceptionHandlingIterable.exceptionOnHasNext(Repres

even though the index is created and the nodes added. The index i create using

node_index=g.get_or_create_index(neo4j.Node, "field_index")

adding the nodes using

batch = neo4j.WriteBatch(g)
for node in nodes:
   batch.add_to_index(neo4j.Node,"field_index","type",node["type"],node)
batch.submit()

How do i indicate that the value of node["type"] is numeric through py2neo? How do i then query for it using CYPHER?

Alternatively, if someone can indicate how else i could create a numeric index using possibly the console that would be appreciated.

Comment: Why has 'type' to be numeric? If you only filter for type:'2' or whatever it should work, no? Maybe I don't get your question ;)